# Unit Tests for Powershell SMO Restore Scripts

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo, unit-testing

I am implementing a collection of scripts to manage backup files and restores. The scripts are based on this article: http://www.solidq.com/sqj/Documents/2010%20September%20Issue/SQJ_003_pag._30-41.pdf

I want to develop Unit Tests around the scripts. I'm interested in using a framework such as [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki) or [PSUnit](http://psunit.org/)

My problem is that I don't understand what I should be looking for in the tests. I'm new to Unit testing, and most of what I have read relies on mocking up files, changing them with a function, and verifying that you can read the value you expect out of the file.

The functions I will build interact with a collection of backup files in some read-only fashion. My first inclination is to create a static directory with a couple of files and store it with my tests. Since the code only reads from the files, the test directory will always stay the same.

This would require storing these backup files in source control, which I don't love. I also don't think this follows in the true spirit of unit tests, but I'm not sure of a better way to do it. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to store backup files in source control. Most DB Unit Tests I have created rely on a local database you re-create from scratch, each run.

Comment: My scripts use backup files rather than databases- so I would have to create the DB from script, then create about 15-20 backups to test my use cases. That might be the right way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

I've used PSUnit in some of the work I've on CodePlex project [SQL Server Powershell Extensions](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com)

Check out the PSUnit test scripts in the source area:
http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/ed45217f200e#Test%20Scripts%2fTest.SQLServer.ps1

There's a test function in the Test.SQLServer.ps1 script for testing invoke-sqlbackup function:

```
##function Test.Invoke-SqlBackup([switch] $Skip)
function Test.Invoke-SqlBackup([switch] $Category_InvokeSql)
{
    #Arrange
    $server = get-sqlserver "$env:computername\sql2k8"
    #Act
    Invoke-SqlBackup "$env:computername\sql2k8" "pubs"  "$($server.BackupDirectory)\pubs.bak" -force
    $Actual = $?
    Write-Debug $Actual
    #Assert
    Assert-That -ActualValue $Actual -Constraint {$ActualValue}
}
```

For any xUnit based framework you'll follow an arrange, act, assert. There might also be a tear down action to perform post clean tasks. As for unit testing in general rather than focus on PSUnit or Pester. Read up on xUnit/nUnit framework concepts.

Comment: Took a look at your tests - looks like you are using a collection of saved backup files to run tests against. I think I will adopt that strategy for the moment, and target scripting a create and backup into the 'Assemble' step at some later date.